# Software for Pi based Wifi Stereo system with multiple clients

Tags: raspbian, wifi, server, radio

What I want to do is install the raspberry pi in my car. What it will do is connect to my speakers in my car and give off a wifi hotspot. This hotspot will not actually connect to the internet. Instead you will connect to it through your phone and multiple people can connect to it and anyone can play music through it coming out of the car radio.

I'd like to do this instead of the two way bluetooth thats already in the car so i can have multiple phones connected to play at any time. I was wondering how to be able to do this with the raspberry pi.

I understand all the hardware but am not sure if there is already software to help speed my project up because its already availiable.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47160/discussion-on-question-by-jacob-dillow-making-a-wifi-stereo-system).

Comment: I can see a potential conflict when more than one user tries to play music at the same time. Does the first one take precedence until the song is finished? Does the next one interrupt the first and take over? Do they play simultaneously, making a mishmash of sound that just becomes noise like with stereo wars? You would have to have some kind of traffic control to decide who goes when. Does one phone have higher precedence that can override the others regardless of its order in line?

Answer (score 0):

You could use shairport to make the Pi work as an AirPlay receiver, then use appropriate software on non-Apple phones to connect to it.

Comment: What about non Apple products?

Comment: There are several software solutions out there that allow Android systems to talk to AirPlay. I'm not sure this is necessarily the *best* solution to the problem, but it's a possible one that leverages existing software that's widely available.